# Is it possible to create post in wordpress using postman?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, rest-api, api

We have tried to create a post in WordPress using postman, can't able to create one since we have received an error as you are not allowed to do this action

Even though I entered the admin login, it gives the same error !!!!

This is the exact error message,

{
"code": "rest_cannot_create",
"message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.",
"data": {
"status": 401
}
}

I have tried using this URL in the postman (post) method http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

And in the authorization entered the admin credentials of my application.

Any alternative solutions are also appreciable .....Thank You!!!

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your questions.

Did you check: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/ ?

From WordPress 5.6 you can set application password in your WordPress profile.